# Linear transformation $R^3 \to R^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Hi just wondering if anyone can give a hand with this question

Suppose $T : R^3 → R^2$
is defined by $T(x, y, z) = (x − y + z, z − 2)$, for $(x, y, z) ∈ R^3$
. 
Is T a linear transformation? Justify your answer.

Thanks

Comment: May be you should first say what you know about linear transformations? Definition of linear transformation?

Comment: @topgeomj to be honest, very little I missed classes due to personal reasons and (due to an unhelpful lecturer) I'm trying to teach myself what I missed

Comment: That is perfectly fine and i am happy that you want to learn it by yourself. Good luck. Please read some book for a definition or at least googling would give a quick response..

Comment: @topgeomj the problem is mainly proofs do you have any tips on what to look up?

Comment: Proofs? I suggest you to solve problems like this before going for any proofs.. Take some maps (you can write down as you wish) and check if that maps satisfy the condition for a map to be linear that is $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$ and $f(ax)=af(x)$  for all $x\in V$ and $a\in \mathbb{R}$

Comment: @topgeomj thanks a mill for your help

Comment: Glad that i could help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Because by taking $(x,y,z)=0$, you have:

$T(0) = (0-0+0,0-2)=(0,-2)$ which is not the zero vector.

Hence it does not satisfy the condition of being a linear transformation.

Alternatively, you can show via the conventional way by considering any $(a,b,c)\& (x,y,z) \in R^3$ and any scalar $k\in R$. Then show whether if the equation:

$T(k(a,b,c)+(x,y,z)) = kT(a,b,c)+T(x,y,z)$

holds or not.